# How to recover to normal election from `staking.StakingElectionFailed` with `Fallback = BoundedExecution`?

Tags: staking

We're running the NPoS chain with Aura, Grandpa instead of Babe.

We've just upgraded our solochain. In this upgrade, we changed `pallet_election_provider_multi_phase::Config::Fallback=BoundedExecution` instead of `NoFallback`.

Due to unfortunate incident while upgrading, the chain stopped producing blocks. However, after solving the incident, the chain continues as normal (thanks to Aura, this is the reason why we choose Aura instead of Babe in the first place). And we know for sure that the staking election will fail because we've encountered this problem before because of the same incident. Back then `NoFallback` is used, the chain stopped working until we solve it by submit election solution through `setEmergencyElectionResult` (thanks to the documentation [here](https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/pallet_election_provider_multi_phase/index.html#emergency-phase)).

In the new upgrade, we use `BoundedExecution` as in this [pull request](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/pull/10905). `BoundedExecution` fallback helps the chain to continue to function even when the `staking.StakingElectionFailed`.

My question is: Can we bring the staking election back to normal instead of relying on `BoundedExecution` fallback?

Logs

```
[1840200]  generated 0 npos voters, 0 from validators and 0 nominators
[#1840200]  Finalized election round with compute Fallback.
[1840200]  chain does not have enough staking candidates to operate for era 1530 (0 elected, minimum is 3)
```

Answer (score 4):

For anyone who may encounter this problem here is the solution and also the explanation.

### Explanation

You may encounter this problem when update older substrate version to the newer one. In my case, it is from `substrate polkadot-v0.9.18` to `substrate polkadot-v0.9.23`.

Tks to @kianenigma suggestion, I've looked into the implementation of `pallet_staking::get_npos_voters()` and found that there is a difference in implementation between older and newer version.

In older version, `pallet_staking::get_npos_voters()` use its `Validators` and `Nominators` storage items to return the voters. While in newer version, `pallet_staking::get_npos_voters()` use `T::VoterList` (which is usually configured to be `pallet_bags_list`) to return the voters.

When we validate/nominate, our votes are not recorded in `T::VoterList` in older implementation while newer implementation already does. And when we switch to the new version, `T::VoterList` is empty. That's why staking election always failed.

### Solution

The solution is to chill your nominators/validators, and validate/nominate again so that new implementation will record your votes in `T::VoterList`. And maybe `forceNewEra()` using `sudo` account. Maybe re-try a couple of times until you see `staking.Elected`.

Answer (score 1):

> `generated 0 npos voters, 0 from validators and 0 nominators`

Your logs are indicating that your chain has no nominators (voters), and no validators either, this is the root cause of the issue.

Otherwise, your steps in using a proper fallback is correct.

Comment: There are already validators. But the staking election is still failed :(. Can you check this, please? https://apps.bholdus.com/?rpc=wss%3A%2F%2Fapi.testnet.bho.network%2Fblockchain-wss#/staking. The log from the node still says 0 validators

Comment: Do you have subscan or some explorer where I can see the details of the blocks in which the election has failed? It does seem like you have 3 validators, but no nominators, and you election process seems fine to me.

Comment: In whichever version of substrate you are, you should look into the `get_npos_voters` function and try and map that to your chain data to try and figure out what is going wrong. Also, it would help if you paste a link to your actual runtime configs.

Comment: just check `get_npos_voters()` implementation. From on-chain state, there are 3 validators, but in the end of `get_npos_voters()`, `all_voters` is 0. @kianenigma

Comment: It could be the `T::VoterList::count()` returns `0`. In the older version of substrate, `all_voters` is calculated from `Validators::count() and Nominators::count()`. I think this is the reason why the election always says that 0 validators in the new substrate version. @kianenigma

Comment: Hi @kianenigma, I found a solution and I will update my answer. Tks a lot for the suggestion to entry for the implementation investigation.