# After upgrading the chain version and elections not happening

Tags: polkadot, runtime-upgrade, versioning, substrate-node

I have a chain running on `polkadot-v0.9.18` and I want to upgrade it to `polkadot-v0.9.20`, so I did a runtime upgrade using the latters `wasm code`and changed the client. After this the elections are not happening and also there is no new era.

How can I fix it?

Log that  I got on terminal [image]

Comment: Can you provide some logs?

Comment: @DaanvanderPlas updated the log

Answer (score 1):

You need to chill all the validators and validate again, elections should start again, this happens due to the different implementation of `npos_elections` in different versions of substrate.

Refer to this [How to recover to normal election from `staking.StakingElectionFailed` with `Fallback = BoundedExecution`?](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/3154/how-to-recover-to-normal-election-from-staking-stakingelectionfailed-with-fal)